# Form wont submit data to MySQL Database

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I have 1 file with my html form and another php file with the code below. I'm able to connect successfully when i click the submit button. But when I refresh my database in phpMyAdmin control panel. No data gets pushed to my database.

**HTML FORM**

```
<form class="well" id="contactForm" name="sendMsg" novalidate="" action="contact_form.php" method="post">
        <div class="control-group">
            <div class="controls">
                <input class="form-control" name="fullname" id="name" type="text" placeholder="Full Name" required="" data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <div class="controls">
                <input class="form-control" name="phonenumber" id="phone" type="text" placeholder="Phone Number" required="" data-validation-required-message="Please enter your phone number" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <div class="controls">
                <input class="form-control" name="emailaddress" id="email-address" type="email" placeholder="Email Address" required="" data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <div class="controls">
                <textarea rows="6" class="form-control" name="message" id="msg" type="msg" placeholder="Enter detailed question/concern, and we will get back to you." required="" data-validation-required-message="Please enter your question/concern"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <div class="controls submit-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

**CONTACT_FORM.PHP**

```
<?php

define('DB_NAME', 'xxx');
define('DB_USER', 'xxx');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'xxx');
define('DB_HOST', 'xxx');

$connection = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

if(!$connection){
die('Database connection failed: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$db_selected = mysqli_select_db($connection, DB_NAME);

if(!$db_selected){
die('Can\'t use ' .DB_NAME . ' : ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}

echo 'Connected successfully';

$name = @$_POST ['fullname'];
$phone = @$_POST ['phonenumber'];
$email = @$_POST ['emailaddress'];
$msg = @$_POST ['message'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO contact_form (fullname, phonenumber, emailaddress, message) VALUES ('$name',   '$phone', '$email', '$msg')";

if (!mysqli_query($connection, $sql)){
die('Error: ' . mysqli_connect_error($connection));
}
?>
```

[image]

Comment: No data (a row with empty fields), or no record (no row)?

Comment: remove those `@` first.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything,  as well as `or die(mysqli_error($connection))` to `mysqli_query()`,

Comment: Your image shows that you are looking at the `database structure` and not `BROWSING the actual data`. **Is that your real problem**?!?! just click on the `BROWSE` tab.

Comment: What I do to troubleshoot things like this is to print $sql; on the line right after your statement, then take that output and dump it into PHPMyAdmin to see if it works, then adjust from there.

Comment: For checking is there some data in your POST array, you can use `var_dump($_POST['fullname']);`

Comment: ...or `var_dump($_POST);` - `print_r($_POST);` and get them all ;)

Comment: See Ashique's answer, that's what is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

First of all use that construction:

```
if (isset($_POST['fullname'])) {
    $name = $_POST['fullname'];
}
```

And so on for other values.

Or better still :-

```
$name = isset($_POST['fullname']) ? $_POST['fullname'] : '';
```

This way the field `$name` is always set to something so you dont get errors when you try and use it later in your code

Comment: @RiggsFolly, does it change anything? I don't think that it is better, this is just another way. IMHO not close to for editing answer

Comment: I can answer that. Using a ternary operator helps to avoid using an `else` statement, which will increase code size, plus you can use a default value. I.e.: `$name = isset($_POST['fullname']) ? $_POST['fullname'] : 'no_name';`

Comment: Your way, if there was nothing in `$_POST['fullname']` the variable `$name` would never be created. So later in your code when you come to do something with it, you would get a `variable does not exist` error. Doing it this way makes sure the variable exists PLUS allows you to set default values when `$_POST['fullname']` does not exist.

Comment: another way, you don't see any error, because your variable equals to void, and you insert into db nothing.

Comment: `$name = isset($_POST['fullname']) ? $_POST['fullname'] : 'no_name';` - "no_name" being a default value ;)

Comment: I guess your sites all run with `display_errors = Off` or they dont run at all.

Comment: nope, in my site I use Java=) I mean that, it is better to add additional line of code with `else` statement to prevent null variable.

Comment: [How many times](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26878720/form-wont-submit-data-to-mysql-database#comment42314722_26878840) do I [have to say it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26878720/form-wont-submit-data-to-mysql-database#comment42314806_26878840). Doing that prevents a null value.

Answer (score 1):

It is clear that you are not passing value for the column ID, ether you alter the column AUTO_INCREMENT, 
[image]
Step 1: Click on change column ID
Step 2: Check A_I (AUTO_INCREMENT)

Step 3: Click Save

Or another way also you can pass value for ID as below:

```
$name = @$_POST ['fullname'];
$phone = @$_POST ['phonenumber'];
$email = @$_POST ['emailaddress'];
$msg = @$_POST ['message'];
$id = 1 // Set value for ID

$sql = "INSERT INTO contact_form (ID, fullname, phonenumber, emailaddress, message) VALUES ($id, '$name',   '$phone', '$email', '$msg')";
```

Comment: That shouldn't matter, not from what I can tell by OP's DB schema/image of.

Comment: ID will not accept NULL, then how will get inserted asper the schema? explain @Fred-ii-

Comment: OP is using `die('Error: ' . mysqli_connect_error($connection))` where should be using `or die(mysqli_error($connection))` -  `mysqli_connect_error` is for connection errors, and not query errors. Probably the reason why OP is not getting errors back saying "Cannot be NULL".

Comment: Definitely, will print "Error:" at least :)

Comment: As per the schema he is not passing the value for ID, that is only reason why the insert is not working, rest all column other than ID will accept NULL.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `@` symbols from your `$_POST` variables, you also need to remove the space. I want to make you aware that you are very exposed to SQL injection without sanitizing/validating those values before inserting them, use `ctype` or `filter_var`. Finally, I would recommend changing your collation from `latin1` to `utf8` unless you have a specific reason for that character set.

You have some extra spaces in your insert values before `$phone` that is probably causing it to fail

```
VALUES ('$name',   '$phone', '$email', '$msg')
```

As stated in another answer, you always need to verify there is data in your variables before trying to use them. Also, if you are redirecting in `contact_form.php, it is very important to put an exit with your failure messages or you may never see them.

```
if($_POST['fullname']){
    $name = $_POST['fullname']
}else{
    echo "name not received";
    exit;
}
if($_POST['phonenumber']){
    $phone = $_POST['phonenumber']
}else{
    echo "phone not received";
    exit;
}
if($_POST['emailaddress']){
    $email = $_POST['emailaddress']
}else{
    echo "email not received";
    exit;
}
if($_POST['message']){
    $msg = $_POST['message']
}else{
    echo "message not received";
    exit;
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO contact_form (fullname, phonenumber, emailaddress, message) 
        VALUES ('$name', '$phone', '$email', '$msg')";

if (!mysqli_query($connection, $sql)){
die('Error: ' . mysqli_connect_error($connection));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO contact_form 
        (fullname, phonenumber, emailaddress, message) 
        VALUES ('$name',   '$phone', '$email', '$msg')";
```

use `"` instead of `'`

Comment: That is what the OP is using `$sql = "INSERT INTO contact_form (fullname, phonenumber, emailaddress, message) VALUES ('$name',   '$phone', '$email', '$msg')";`

Comment: Make sure you catch mistakes by the OP before you repost them.